# Multiplying elements of a list python

Tags: python

I got a list with elements:

```
table = [ [[0.,0.,1.],[0.,0.,-1.],[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]],
          [srB(0, 0),srA(0, 0),[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]],
          [spB(Beta, Alpha, PHI), spC(PHI), spA( Alpha, PHI), [0.,0.,0.]],
          [[0.,0.,0.], [0.,0.,0.], srA(0, 0), srB(0, 0)],
          [spB(Beta,Alpha,PHI), spC(PHI), [0.,0.,0.], [0.,0.,0.]],
          [stB(Beta,Alpha,PHI), stC(Beta,Alpha), stA(Beta, PHI), stD(Alpha)]
```

It corresponds to the table in the following shape:

```
    A    B    C    D
    ------------------
rco|     
rnc|
Alp|
rnn|
Bet|
T  |
```

I want to obtain a table of a type:

```
    rco rnc Alp rnn Bet rnn Bet T
     -----------------------------
rco |
rnc |
Alp |      SOME RESULTS
rnn |
Bet |
T   |
```

which comes from a dot product of elements on each side of table. I mean,

1. for each element `rco` create dot product with each element `rco` and sum them up
2. for each element `rco` create dot product with each element `rnc` and sum them up
3. for each element `rco` create dot product with each element `Alp` and sum them up
   etc.

I have tried by the following mutiplication:

```
 S = np.zeros((6,6))
    for i in range(len(stable)):
            for j in range(4):
                    for k in range(len(stable)):
                            for l in range(4):
                                  S[i][k] += np.dot(stable[i][j], stable[k][l])
```

Update:
It seems I solved the problem. However I am wondering how I can simplify my multiplication. The element reaped and what I need to to is obtaining only an upper triangular matrix.
I'd be happy for a hint.

Comment: What does srB(0,0) return? A row vector of length 3, like [0. , 0., 0.]? Were you intending to multiply a row vector * a col vector and get a dot product? (You can't multiply two row vectors by each other and get a scalar.)

Comment: yes, srB(0,0) returns vector like [0. , 0., 0.]

Comment: When multiplying two row vectors to get a dot product, you'll have to transpose the second one (so it becomes a column vector).

Comment: It looks like you are writing these for real (as opposed to doing this for homework). I'd suggest that you look at the numpy tutorial (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html). It provides a way for python users to multiply vectors easily.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for very useful hints!